# How to use InstallShield 2012 TrialWare feature with 64 bits application?

Tags: c#, c++, 64-bit, installshield, trialware

I'm trying to use trialware feature on my setup.

Main application is a c# .net application which target any cpu (32 bits and 64 bits).
So i created a pure win32 dll in c++ and wrapped it using trialware. Loaded by [ImportDll] in c# code, it works well... If system is 32 bits !

So i generated a 64 bits version of my security dll and now application is loading either 32 or 64 bits dll based on computer CPU.

My problem: no way to wrap this 64 bits dll with InstallShield 2012 trialware (error -7102)... Which make this feature completly useless for us.
Has someone any idea about this issue and how to solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on Flexera community forum and an InstallShield Software Engineer answered me: http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=199956

To make it short it is not possible to do so, it is a limitation of IS 2012.
My own solution will be to force a x86 compilation dedicated to trialware feature.